# how to use nextAll to find all inputs using jquery/

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, focus

i have this html:

```
        <div class="field phone">
            <input type="text" maxlength="3" />
        </div>
        <div class="field phone number1">
            <input type="text" maxlength="3" />
        </div>
        <div class="field phone number2">
            <input type="text" maxlength="4" />
        </div>
```

then i'm using

```
    $(".phone input:not(:last)").keydown(function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (that.prevValue != $(that).val()) {
                that.prevValue = $(that).val();
                if ($(that).val().length == $(that).attr("maxlength")) {
                    $(that).nextAll("input")[0].focus();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

the issue is that `$(that).nextAll("input")[0]` returns undefined, instead of a input selector and i cant use `focus()` on it

any ideas what is happening here? thanks

Comment: .next and .nextAll only select siblings, not cousins. It's in the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/nextall/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace:

```
$(that).nextAll("input")[0].focus();
```

with something like

```
$(that).parent().next(".phone").find("input").focus();
```

As Kevin B said, `.next` and `.nextAll` only work on siblings, so you need to go back up to the parent, over to the parent's sibling, and then down to the child.